# Objective C - Using deleteCharactersInRange for NSMutableStrings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

How would I use deleteCharactersInRange to remove the first character of a NSMutableString?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not that hard...

```
NSMutableString *a = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"aString"];
NSRange range;
range.location = 0;
range.length = 1;
[a deleteCharactersInRange:range];
```

You can shorten the range creation like this:

```
NSRange range = {0,1}; // edit: of course 0,1 instead of 1,0, thanks Omar
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked but I have to point out that to remove the first character, it would be: 
NSRange range = {0,1};
not
NSRange range = {1,0};

Comment: It's just as simple (and arguably better practice?) to use NSMakeRange(), an inline function defined by Cocoa. For example: NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,1); Either way works, although this idiom is a common practice and is more likely to be recognized broadly.